# How can I convert time (time zone)

Tags: excel, vba, date, time

I want to convert the time zone with 15 hours difference in excel. I can do in excel sheet by the following equation:

```
 =E1-(15/24)
```

E1 is time zone1 data with this format: (mm/dd/yy hh:mm). 
I don't know How can I write code of this formula in macro. Could you help me to write code?

Comment: DateAdd("h", -15, dt)

Comment: You can use the exact same logic you already have (or above from Kevin) in a macro. You just need to switch `E1` with a VBA range ( like `Range("E1")`)

Comment: @Kevin How Can I apply `DateAdd("h", -15, dt)` to Range of another column? when I apply `Sub TimeZone()

    Dim dt As Date 
    dt = Range("E3:E11")
    Range("M3:M11") = DateAdd("h", -15, dt)
End Sub` show me error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
Sub TimeZone()
Range("M3:M11").Formula = "=E3 - (15/24)"
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`LocalTime = Range("E1") - (15/25)` will work just the same but there is a condition.

E1 must hold a date/time value which is a number with decimals, like 43886.5 which would present 12 noon at today's date. If you deduct 15 hours from that you arrive at last night's 9 pm.

Comment: Since OP says his equation already works it's  implied his formats are correct

Comment: @urdearboy Since OP thinks its important to tell us the format of E1 it implied that he doesn't know the value of that cell. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just swap Excel references *`E1`* for VBA references *`Range("E1")`*

---

`Range("E1") = Range("E1") - (15/24)`

Comment: Can't help you much with that info. The type of error would help....

Comment: So you value in `Range("E1") ` may not actually be a date but is instead text that just looks like a date. There are **many** solutions on this site that can help you fix that

Comment: Well there is not nearly enough information for me to begin to debug. Try posting another question with your new code and explain the specific issue you have (what line the code fails) and show the sample data that is associated with the failure